# Why are parts of my scene not visible after rendering?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, camera

This probably has already been asked, but I couldn't find it so

[image]

(there's only one camera in the scene)

Comment: Your camera is probably ok, but your objects are not rendered: have a look on the upper right part of the screen capture (the outliner) in your question: little camera icons are grayed (so objects are not rendered)

Comment: Not trying to be mean (asking to see how we could do better) What did you search for? Yes this has been asked many, many times before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got answered by Lemon, the camera icons were grayed out in the Outliner.
[image]